# Не могу скачать пакет hddtemp Ubuntu 22.04 desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

«Не найдёшь кондидат на установку»
Скачивание пакета exfatprogs не помогло, lm-sensors тоже. Помогите

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Пакет hddtemp был удалён, потому что он устаревший, неживой и не нужный в 2022 году. Подробнее тут https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1002484

Comment: Если тебе надо смарты и текущую температуру смотреть - `smartmontools` - вполне себе нормальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Пакет устаревший. В интернете предлагается такой вариант:

```
sudo apt update
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hddtemp/hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb
```

Источник:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403900/how-to-install-exfat-utils-and-hddtemp-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Попробую!) спасибо :)